# Is it possible to do custom actions in ClickOnce deployment?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, clickonce

Is it possible to do custom actions or have a custom user interface while doing [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) deployment in [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework)?

My situation is to accept some user credentials and store it in a text file while deploying of a Windows application.

Comment: Do you want to show the custom interface, before the application is downloaded?

Comment: yes.I need to show interface on that time

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to implement your own logic in this state of the deployment. But you could implement your logic into the website that contains the link to your application.